# How to find the inverse permutation?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, permutation

Suppose I have an unknown vector `v`, and a permutation `p`.

How can I reconstruct `v` from `v(p)` and `p`?

An equivalent question would be to find a permutation `q` such that `p(q) = [1 2 ... n]`?

Since this is going to run in a tight loop, I need the answer to be vectorized (and efficient).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the inverse permutation `q` of `p`, it won't get more efficient than:

```
q(p) = 1:numel(p);
```

You can thus reconstruct `v` from `vp = v(p)` and `p` via:

```
q(p) = 1:numel(p);
v = vp(q);
```

or even faster without explicitly constructing `q`:

```
v(p) = vp;
```

(You might have noticed that `v = vp(q)` corresponds to `v == P^(-1)*vp` and `v(p) = vp` corresponds to `P*v == vp` for appropriate permutation operators (matrices) `P = sparse(1:numel(p),p,1)` and `P^(-1)==P.'==sparse(p,1:numel(p),1)`. Thus yielding the same result.)

If you use this in a loop, do however mind to properly reset `q` or `v` respectively to `[]` before this operation. In case of changing length of `p`, you would otherwise get wrong results if the new `p` was shorter than the old `p`.

Comment: This could be interesting as OP is looking to run it in a tight loop, so that `1:numel(P)` could be stored in a vector and used iteratively in that tight loop! So, that way this could be more efficient.

Comment: This is a smart and fast method! You will however get problems if you put it in a loop and p gets fewer elements at some point, but if you add something like `q=q(1:numel(p));` afterwards it will be fixed (and still be faster than my method).

Comment: @JensBoldsen: Yes, `q` or `v` resp. should be empty before this, to make it work properly. I added it to the answer to clarify.

Comment: Can you please share what's going on behind the scenes here?

Comment: @amit: I did add some clarification. Maybe an example could help clarify.
`p(1:4) = [4,3,2,1]`, the inverse permutation could be defined as: `q([4,3,2,1]) = 1:4`. More descriptively `p: (4->1, 3->2, 2->3, 1->4)`, whereas `q: (4<-1, 3<-2, 2<-3, 1<-4)`.

Answer (score 8):

To find the inverse permutation I usually use:

```
[~,q] = sort(p);
```

Which is faster than the methods suggested by Divakar.

Comment: obviously, sort and take the indices. simple, will give it a shot. thanks.

Comment: Yup this should be quite efficient!

Answer (score 2):

With `ismember` -

```
[~,q] = ismember(1:numel(p),p)
```

With `intersect` -

```
[~,~,q] = intersect(1:numel(p),p)
```

With `bsxfun` -

```
[q,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq,[1:numel(p)],p(:)))
```

Comment: Care to mention the complexity of these functions, and how much will it cost to run this approach? (big O notation would be fine) My fear it will run in quadric time, which is not an option for me.

Comment: @amit What's your `ndims(v)`?

Comment: As I stated, `v` is a *vector*, so `ndims(v) = 2`

Comment: @amit.. Ah, didn't you mean [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) by permutation? Basically I assumed you have a multidimensional array, `v` whose dimensions you would like to `permute` with `q` as the dimensions array. Guess I made a mistake in assuming that?

Comment: @amit I think `numel(p)` would make sense there instead. Edited with it.